# Getting Array From Mysql database and get data from user in form of array ,how insert data array into fetched Array Php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i'm geting data from user from form and storing that data in $data array ,**1st time** it insert array in to
main array Like [{sub array1} ] **2nd time** get new data from user again and fetch data from database and
insert new data array into fetched array
Data should be upload like
**[{sub array1} ,{sub array2}]**

Comment: try to be clear, post exactly what you want.

Comment: @PascalTovohery can you write  php code for this ...what you need to understand?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what u are asking for but an easy way of storing/getting array from a database is just storing your array as a string separated by a character like **","** or **";"** (of course make sure you don't use it in your string)
like:

```
// code to upload array as string
$array = array("1","2","3");
$arraytostring = '';
$arraycounter = 1; // counter for check the last element
foreach($array as $element){
   $arraytostring .= $element;
   if($arraycounter != count($array)){ // don't print the char if this is the last
      $arraytostring .= ",";
   }
}
// now $arraytostring is your array as a text then you can upload with your db script
// the code to easily retrieve the array

$array = explode(',',$row['column']);
```